# Dynamic and generic search for specific object in datasource

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, generics, entity-framework-4

I have a windows forms application using Entity Framework and LINQ
And there are many forms that i use BindingNavigator with it to navigate through data and i want to add a textBox in the navigator to search for specific item and navigate to it which i did for one from, but now i have to do the same steps for the others forms and add the same events and code in every form, so i decided to make a custom ToolStripTextBox and i use it in every form instead, but i have to make it generic because every form using different objects or entities and this what i come up with :

```
class ToolStripSearchBox<T> : ToolStripTextBox
{
    BindingSource dataSource;
    int currentIndex;

    public ToolStripSearchBox()
        : base()
    {
        KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(ToolStripSearchBox_KeyUp);
    }

    void ToolStripSearchBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F4)
        {
            string patern = Text;
            List<T> TList = dataSource.List.Cast<T>().ToList();
            int res = 0;
            T foundT = default(T);

            if (int.TryParse(patern, out res))
            {
                foundT = TList.Where(j => j. == res).First();

            }
            else
            {
                foundT = TList.First(j => (j.FirstName + " " + j.LastName).Contains(patern));
            }
            if (foundT == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            dataSource.Position = dataSource.IndexOf(foundT);
        }
    }
}
```

But the problem is that every entity has a different properties to filter with, i was thinking to use string parameters to pass the object properties names but i didn't find a way to use it with LINQ.

Sorry if there are dictation mistakes but English isn't my first language
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what I see in your code, by "every entity has a different properties to filter with" you mean the properties like `FirstName`, `LastName`, etc..

If that's the case, quite simply, you can define a generic function object to be used as the matcher. You could specified this at construction time or during initialization. (I'm not very fond of components with parameter-less constructors.)

```
class ToolStripSearchBox<T> {
    public Func<T, string, bool> Matcher { get; set; }
}
```

For example, during initialization of one of these boxes meant to search for `Foo`'s, you would do:

```
ToolStripSearchBox<Foo> fooSearchBox = new ToolStripSearchBox<Foo>();
fooSearchBox.Matcher = (j, pattern) => (j.Second + " " + j.Second).Contains(pattern);
```

That said, you have a bunch of issues with your code: Bear in mind that the `First()` extension method will trow an exception if no element is found; use `FirstOrDefault()`. I see that you're also using `foundT == null`.. I doubt that would even compile. Do `foundT == default(T)` instead.

```
class ToolStripSearchBox<T> {

    void ToolStripSearchBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        ...
            foundT = TList.FirstOrDefault(this.Matcher(j, patern));
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i think that's what i want and you are right about FirstOrDefault() and foundT == null yes it will not compile
i will give it a try